# Global onStart on Play Framework 2.3.7 not working?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

Sorry if this question turns to be silly, but I simply cannot find my mistake and I checked already plenty of posts here in SO and other sites.
I have setup a Play 2.3.7 project using Java. I have created a Global.java file in the common package under the app directory. In that file I override onStart (and other hooks) but I don't get them to work. They simply do not execute at all. Here's the Global.java file:

```
package common;

import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.beforeStart(application);
        throw new RuntimeException("WTF");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.onStart(application);
        throw new RuntimeException("WTF");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.onStop(application);
        throw new RuntimeException("WTF");
    }
}
```

And inside the application.conf, here's the relevant part, which is commented by default:

```
# Define the common.Global object class for this application.
# Default to common.Global in the root package.
# application.global=common.Global
```

What can be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Global` object must reside in the default package,  so you need to remove `package common`.

As stated in the first paragraph of the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal).

Comment: Well, it works if I move it to the default package, indeed. Thanks. Now, the generated comments are a bit misleading mentioning the common package by default. Also, I tried to relocate Global.java somewhere else and use application.global=the.new.package.Global, but it doesn't work: it throws some exception and the application doesn't start. Any ideas?

Comment: You can only use `application.global` to change the class name of the `Global` object. e.g. `application.global=SomethingGlobal`, but you can't relocate it to a different package.

Comment: Well, I just moved and renamed Global.java to common.SomethingElse.java, added application.global=common.SomethingElse and it worked. So I guess you are wrong about that. Thanks in any case.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you forgot to uncomment the application.global setting.

The following code worked just fine for me.

Global.java file:

```
package common;

import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.beforeStart(application);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.onStart(application);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application application) {
        Logger.error("good bye cruel world");
        super.onStop(application);
    }
}
```

application.conf file:

```
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
application.global=common.Global
```